# QuickTime video codec configuration

Tags: macos, quicktime, codec, avi

So I'm porting an app from Windows to Mac, and part of the app deals with creating movie files.  On Windows, there's a group of functions like ICOpen and ICConfigure, which signify to the video compression driver to open up a configuration box for the selected codec.  Is there anything like that for QuickTime on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use straight Quicktime-C calls for this, but the function you want is called MovieExportDoUserDialog.

See the [QTMovieExportSettings](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?QTMovieExportSettings) article on CocoaDev for the full details.

Comment: Too bad, I'm limited to QTKit and 64-bit.  Still, thanks for the answer.